# Files backed up to icloud in swift are changed when the app is deleted

Tags: swift

Added backup and restore functions to the app
And it works fine until I delete the app
But if you delete the app and reinstall it, the file name you backed up is changed
The backup.db file is changed to .backupp.db.icloud when you reinstall the app after deleting it

And after the backup file, which was normal before deleting the app, is changed to .icloud, it seems that the file is not normal.

Below is the Info.plist and the source code
What's the problem?

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
        <key>iCloud.com.sinwho.CheckDay</key>
        <dict>
                <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
                <string>CheckDay</string>
                <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
                <string>Any</string>
         </dict>
</dict>
```

```
func copyiCloudToLocal() throws -> Bool {
        var result:Bool = false
        
        let dbFileURL = CloudDataManager.DocumentsDirectory.dbFileURL.appendingPathComponent(Define.DB_NAME)
        guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") else
        {
            return result
        }
  
        let iCloudFileURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent(Define.DB_NAME)
        
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudFileURL.path)
        {
            return false
        }
 
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbFileURL.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dbFileURL)
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: iCloudFileURL, to: dbFileURL)
            result = true
        } else {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: iCloudFileURL, to: dbFileURL)
            result = true
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: "Added backup and restore functions to the app And it works fine until I delete the app But if you delete the app and reinstall it, the file name you backed up is changed The backup.db file is changed to .backupp.db.icloud when you reinstall the app after deleting it"  In English, each sentence ends with the period.

Comment: Thanks for the reply El Tomato
The problem is, if you delete and reinstall the app, the file is converted abnormally.
If the original file size was 16387 bytes, after reinstalling it, it is changed to 187 bytes.
Of course the file is also corrupted I don't know what the problem is